# PHP require properly includes script, but it's contents are seemingly not being read

Tags: php, require

I am trying to require some configuration files that, for security reasons, are outside of any directory accessible through the web. The location of the file is /var/www/config/admin.php.

```
require '/var/www/config/admin.php';
```

Even though the file is required and PHP does not return any error (it does when I change the dir of the require for testing purposes), PHP seemingly ignores the contents of the require. For instance, if I put

```
die("foobar");
```

the script does not exit. The script also does not give a syntax error if I put garbage in the require.

The require is in global scope, outside of any function, at the top of the file. I am calling that file through another require in another script inside the web server. Something like this:

```
''user'' -> login.php > require 'database.php' > require '/var/www/config/admin.php'
```

The require inside of login.php is properly read and parsed.

Why is PHP not reading or parsing the contents of the (last) require?

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the right admin.php file? Try to `echo file_get_conttents('/var/www/config/admin.php');` and see if it prints its code.

Comment: It correctly prints the contents of the file. But for some reason it prints them twice. I think what is happening is that the .php file is interpreted as plaintext, since it also prints the contents of the file when I add die(); directly after the require. I wasn't previously able to see this, because my script always redirected to another page depending on the outcome of a certain function.

My problem was fixed by adding <?php to the top of the required file. I just overlooked it for some reason. Thank you for the clue! ;)

Comment: Did you even add `<?php` at the beginning of that file? :)

Comment: @Jeto nope, forgot! I guess I'll need another cup of coffee. ;)